# Change javascript depending on what's checked in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So basically, I need a piece of javascript magic.
I want to have a form with multiple checkboxes (representing webpages) and as people check these boxes "on" or "off", it will generate a different javascript.

The idea is to give my visitors a button, that would link them too all the webpages they selected in the form, with a one single click. Am I making any sense here...?

So some sort of script that would turn parts of itself off when certain conditions are met within the form.

I hope some genius mastermind is able to help me here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope some genius asker is able to provide us with some of his code here and might tell us what he has already tried so far… ;-)

Comment: It appears as if you don't quite grasp what you can do with a function.  A function can check conditions and do a variety of things, not just a single task.  Whether you want to launch a bunch of windows or if you want to generate a bunch of links that the user can click, it should be a fairly simple task.  (Side note: I didn't down vote you, because I think I see genuine confusion that others could possibly be having too...so don't hate me cause others have.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need some wizard code, you just need the code to open many separate windows.

You don't need JavaScript that rewrites itself, you need a bunch of if-statements that open windows if the option is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).each( function () {
    if( $( 'input[name="check"]:checked' ) ) {
       window.open( 'url', 'window name', 'window settings' );
    }
});
```

This will look at every radio button and if it's checked it'll open a new window for you. You can do your conditional statement by using name, class, value, or whatever you think fits.